# How can I get the first three letters of a string in JQuery?

Tags: jquery

How can I get the first three letters of a string in JQuery?

For example: Turn cat1234 to cat

Comment: You can use `charAt()` for it works on IE, Chrome, Firefox, Safari and Opera. [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charAt)

Comment: A question that had 24 up votes and has 4 replies and 67 up votes is not constructive?

Answer (score 55):

No jQuery needed! Just use the substring method:

```
var name = "cat1234"

var variable2 = name.substring(0, 3);
```

Answer (score 20):

Use `.slice(start, end)` with start and end values:

```js
var str = 'cat1234';
document.body.innerHTML = str.slice(0, 3);
```

With javascript you can use a regular expression with `.match()` method to exclude the number and get the string value.

```js
var str ='cat1234',
    rg = /[a-zA-Z]+/g,
    ns = str.match(rg);

document.body.innerHTML = ns[0];
```

Answer (score 7):

you could also do:

```
var str = "cat1234";
console.log( str.substr(0, 3));
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [substring()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring):

```
"cat1234".substring(0,3);
```

It means "get all the characters starting at position 0 up to position 3".

Please note this is not a JQuery function, it's plain Java Script.