# How get the first three letters of a string in JQuery or Java?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code

```
{foreach from=$last_user item=s}
  <span class="sp_1">{$s.username}</span>
{/foreach}
```

I want only show three first letter of `{$.username}` .

If i need JavaScript or jQuery please write full code.

Comment: {$s.username.substring(0,3)} will work

Comment: not even a tiny effort!

Comment: No , because I'm a novice . i just  google and find it can be done by javascript or jquery . but i can't work with both so i need ready code for that

Comment: @naveentamanam  {$s.username.substring(0,3)} =>  page can't lode and show white page .

Comment: @Pedram I understand , I am really novice .

Comment: @user2347510 what is this codes? is this angular? or what?

Comment: @Pedram this is ready script (PHP script) and i just edit tpl files . this code show last 10 registered user .

Comment: Information given is not precise, you have added java tag instead of javascript. Little more specific would help.

Answer (score 0):

you just have to use `substring(startingFromIndex, endingIndex)`

```
{foreach from=$last_user item=s}
    <span class="sp_1">{$s.username.substring(0, 3)}</span>
{/foreach}
```

Here is a [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15196706/how-can-i-get-the-first-three-letters-of-a-string-in-jquery/15196768) for a similar question